# What has changed in C++17 in terms of MOVE elision

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision

Is the "move elision" guaranteed in C++17? Let me explain what I mean by that. In almost every article on what C++17 has introduced, one can find the term: "guaranteed copy elision for RVO" which is kinda self-explanatory. But what about move construction?

Let's look at the code below, it's simple there is a non-copyable type, and two functions, one takes NonCopyable parameter by value, and the second one takes it by rvalue reference.

```
#include <iostream>

struct NonCopyable
{
  NonCopyable() = default;
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;

  NonCopyable(NonCopyable&& other) noexcept
  {
    std::cout << "Move ctor\n";
  }
};

void func_by_value(NonCopyable cp)
{
  auto x = std::move(cp);
}

void func_by_rvalue_ref(NonCopyable&& cp)
{
  auto x = std::move(cp);
}

int main() 
{
  std::cout << "Pass by value:\n";
  func_by_value(NonCopyable());

  std::cout << "\nPass by rvalue_ref\n";
  func_by_rvalue_ref(NonCopyable());
}
```

I compiled it two times using GCC(trunk) using the following flags, and the results are slightly different.

> (1) -O0 -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors

```
Program output: 

Pass by value:
Move ctor
Move ctor

Pass by rvalue_ref
Move ctor
```

> (2) -O0 -std=c++17 -fno-elide-constructors

```
Program output:

Pass by value:
Move ctor

Pass by rvalue_ref
Move ctor
```

So my question is - what has changed that the move constriction was elided when using C++17?
[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/feYWec4q7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++17 [mandatory elision of copy/move operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) was introduced:

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:
>
> - ...
> - In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is
>   a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the
>   variable type:
>
>   ```
>   T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>   ```

In the initialization of the parameter `cp` from the prvalue `NonCopyable()`, the move construction is required to be elided. Note that mandatory copy elision works for both copy operation and move operation.