# Is move elision guaranteed in this case?

Tags: c++, c++20, move-semantics, copy-elision

Consider the following C++20 code; assume `T` to be non-movable and non-copyable:

```cpp
struct Cell
{
    Cell(T&& instance) : obj(std::move(instance)) {}

private:
    T obj;
};

Cell cell(T{/* arguments */});
```

Is move elision guaranteed in the constructor of `Cell`?

If `T` were movable, would it be guaranteed that only the regular (non-move) constructor would be invoked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What has changed in C++17 in terms of MOVE elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185398/what-has-changed-in-c17-in-terms-of-move-elision)

Comment: @OP This will not work because you're trying to initialize `obj` with `std::move(instance)` when `T` is neither copyable nor movable.

Comment: Why would you expect copy/move elision to be possible here? Would you expect it to be possible when calling a function `void f(T&& instance) { auto obj = std::move(instance); }` with `f(T{/*args*/})` as well or is there something special you see about constructors?

Comment: Anyway, short answer: A suitable constructor for move-construction must be usable and will be called once and this call must not be elided. Elision through reference binding is never possible. The only way to elide such a copy/move into a class member is by using aggregate initialization. I am sure there is a matching duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is move elision guaranteed in the constructor of Cell?

No, the parameter `instance` of `Cell::Cell(T&& instance)` is of rvalue reference type `T&&`, so there can be no move elision here. The parameter `instance` must bind to the **materialized temporary** `T{/* arguments */}`. Then,  `std::move(instance)` will be used to direct initialize `obj`.

But note that `obj(std::move(instance)` won't work because you're trying to initialize `obj` with `std::move(instance)` when `T` is neither movable neither copyable. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/OKnufSO17)